Error: NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for CacheService: (?) after upgrading angular 15 to 17
    
    providers: [
        CacheService,
        {provide: CacheStorageAbstract, useClass: CacheMemoryStorage},
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: HttpHeaderInterceptor,
            multi: true,
        },
    


checked the ng2-cache version is up to date to its higher version   "ng2-cache": "^0.2.1" help me to fix the issue.
error deatils: Error: NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for CacheService: (?) after upgrading angular 15 to 17
